# How can I Change the Email's Footer Name in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-9, laravel-breeze, laravel-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBmoZ.png)
i'm facing this problem. anyone please guide me and help me to solve this problem

Comment: Share your sample how you are using it, ex: give your, model, view, controller sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean laravel's default email view.

1. Run the command to publish laravel's default email view files:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

2. Open `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/footer.blade.php` and change the `$slot` variable to what you want:

```html
<tr>
<td>
<table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td class="content-cell" align="center">
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }} <-- here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```